# How to tell what computer a query came from in a trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers, audit

I created a trigger for auditing purposes that logs changes made to a particular table.

Is there any way for me to tell what computer the query that set the trigger off came from?  I have full access to the database, but no access to software code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd include these in your auditing:

```
SELECT 
    HOST_NAME()  ModifiedByHost, 
    SYSTEM_USER  ModifiedByUser,
    APP_NAME()  ModifiedByAppName
```

HOST_NAME() will give you the computer.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178598.aspx